# Can you use htaccess to redirect a subdomain to a file?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a bunch of subdomains mapped to my root html folder, but instead of loading the index.php file I want visitors to the subdomains to see a file in that folder named login.php instead.

Visitors to

```
user-a.mydomain.com
user-b.mydomain.com
```

etc, should load the file:

```
mydomain.com/login.php
```

But I don't want the path in the address bar to change.

Is this possible? I don't understand htaccess very well.

M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ login.php [L]
```

This condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^user-` is to make sure that rule only impacts a subdomain starting with `user-`

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll try it out now. What rewrite rule can i use if I want match a subdomain that doesn't have 'user' in front? Eg: there's one called demo.mydomain.com as well.